# Pyspark error while running a pyspark program in pycharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

I am seeing this error when I run a simple pyspark program in pycharm.

```
from py4j.protocol import Py4JError
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py4j'

Can anyone help me in fixing this error?

Comment: Why are you coding against Py4J?

Comment: I am running the pyspark code using python interpreter.

Comment: have you tried this solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342655/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-py4j